# jquery how to decide if a function is run in page loading?

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function(with 200+ lines code). It could run when page loading or during some click events. Now how to decide if a function is run in page loading?

Here is a simple test code. also save in http://jsfiddle.net/EjcTk/ , Thanks.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function ABC() {
        //many code here
        if(someelse===undefined){
                           //if by click, do some code.
                           //if by page loading, do not run these code.
            alert('ok');//check if it works.
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var someelse = 1;
                  ABC();                   
    });
    $('#click').click(function() {
        ABC();
    });
});
</script>
<div id="click">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function ABC(status) {
    //many codes here
    if(status==='click'){
        //if by click, do some code.
        //if by page loading, do not run these code.
        alert('ok');//check if it works.
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    ABC('default');                   
});
$('#click').click(function() {
    ABC('click');
});
```

​

Comment: That's my suggestion too.  Pass a parameter with ABC() and you can know if the function is called on load, click, hover, or with any other circumstance.  It's an easy way to pass state or other data.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/EjcTk/2/

```
var someelse = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    someelse = 0;

    ABC();
});
$('#click').click(function() {
    someelse = 1;
    ABC();
});
function ABC() {
    if (someelse == 0) {
        alert('onload');
    } else alert('onclick');
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pass boolean argument` in function to know if it is call on load or from some where else

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function ABC(isOnLoad) {
        //many code here
        if(isOnLoad){
                           //if by click, do some code.
                           //if by page loading, do not run these code.
            alert('ok');//check if it works.
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {

                  ABC(true);                   
    });
    $('#click').click(function() {
        ABC(false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, depending on how you've set up your click handlers, you could do something like:

```
if(this===window)
    //it's running in page load
else
    //it's being run as a click handler
```

There are a few scenarios where this wouldn't work, for example if you modified `this` manually, or if your click handlers were set up like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "ABC()">Click</a>
```

In this case, `this` would still refer to window. If this is the case, you could do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
this.someVar = true;
function ABC(){
    if (window.someVar === true)
    //its running in doc.ready
    else
    //its running elsewhere
}
this.someVar = false;
//...
//rest of code
//...
});
```